# SQL to filter by the account number

Tags: php, sql

I need to update the SQL to filter by the account number I want to query: This code display the account that correspondents to the value of the &memid = 3. I think giving $memid a value will limit my filtering.How can I make a sql where I will enter account number then will display the correspondent account.

```
$memid = 3; // example
$sql = "SELECT member.*, account.* FROM member, account WHERE member.mem_id = 
account.mem_id AND member.mem_id = '".$memid."' ";
```

here is the whole code:

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'password';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$memid = 3; // example
$sql = "SELECT member.*, account.* FROM member, account WHERE member.mem_id =  
account.mem_id AND member.mem_id = '".$memid."' ";

mysql_select_db('databaseName');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
 die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
echo "Account Number:{$row['Account_Number']}  <br> ".
     "First Name: {$row['fname']} <br> ".
     "Last Name: {$row['lname']} <br> ".
     "Address: {$row['address']} <br> ".
     "Contact: {$row['contact']} <br> ".
     "Share Capital: {$row['Share_Capital']} <br> ".
     "Regular Savings: {$row['Regular_Savings']} <br> ".
     "Power Savings: {$row['Power_Savings']} <br> ".
     "--------------------------------<br>";
} 
echo "Fetched data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated. Look into mysqli or pdo...

Comment: `WHERE Account_Number = your_acc_num`?

Comment: can you paste the structure of member and account tables? it seems you need to join the accountid column.

Comment: Clearly you're only just starting to learn, so do yourself a favour and learn to use MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements and bind variables rather than learning using the old, deprecated MySQL extension with all its associated problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you need to retrieve only certain fields, do not use *.
If the table members and the account table has a field with the same name, use the AS expression.
Also it is better to join the tables using JOIN
SQL Example:

```
SELECT a.mem_id AS memberid,a.Account_Number AS accnum, %etc.% FROM member AS a
INNER JOIN account AS b ON a.mem_id = b.mem_id 
WHERE a.mem_id = '%id%';
```

In the result of mysql_fetch_array you get to $row variable array with unique keys that you set in AS statement:

```
Array ("memberid"=>"%id%","accnum"=>"%Account_Number from DB%", %etc.%)
```

PS: English is not my native language, thanks for understanding and feel free to correct me when necessary.